# SMART vector for RAW pointers in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm using an old open-source library, with the following (simplified) API of interest:

```
// some class that holds a raw pointer to memory on the heap
// DOES NOT delete it in its destructor
// DOES NOT do a "deep" copy when copied/assigned (i.e., after copying both objects
// will point to the same address)
class Point;

// function used to construct a point and allocate its data on the heap
Point AllocPoint();
// function used to release the memory of the point's data
void DeallocPoint(Point& p);

// Receives a pointer/c-array of Points, along with the number of points
// Doesn't own the memory
void Foo(Point* points, int npts);
```

What's the best (safest/most readable/most elegant) way of using this API in C++11. I can't simply use `vector<unique_ptr<Point, PointDeleter>>` (where `PointDeleter` is a simple custom deleter I can implement), because then I will not be able to use the function `Foo` (which expects `Point*` and not `unique_ptr<Point>*`).

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the [boost pointer container library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is "ditch the library." Seriously.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option for me...

Comment: "because then I will not be able to use the function `Foo`" - Why not? `std::unique_ptr::get` will give you a raw pointer while retaining ownership.

Comment: Yes, but to use Foo I need a *C-Array* of points, so how can I pass all the points in the vector?

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to make it look nice, you're probably going to have to write a set of really comprehensive wrappers which completely hide the library's API - effectively, wrap the entire library with one that behaves in a modern C++ way on the outside and hides all the mess inside.

Not a pleasant task, but if you can get the behaviour of that library right then it should make your life a lot easier in the long term. Might not be worth it if you're not going to use this external library very extensively though.

Answer (score 4):

I would wrap this non-RAII C-like API in **RAII** building blocks, and then use them in C++11 code.

For example: you can define a `RaiiPoint` class that wraps the (non-RAII) `Point` class, and in its constructor calls `AllocPoint()`, in the destructor `DeallocPoint()`. Then you can define proper copy constructor and copy `operator=`, or just implement move semantics (with move constructor and move `operator=`), or make the wrapper class both copyable and movable, basing on your requirements.

Then you can simply use a `std::vector<RaiiPoint>` with your RAII-based wrapper class.

(This is a *general* approach that you can use when you want to use C libraries in modern C++ code: you can wrap the "raw" C library handles and objects in safe RAII boundaries, and use these robust safe wrapper classes in your modern C++ code.)

Comment: The problem with this is that he can't pass a `RaiiPoint*` to his functions.  He would have to wrap each of the relevant functions with a function which extracts the `Point`, and passes it.  (It's also not clear that he _can_ implement correct copy or move semantics.)

Comment: I could also used unique_ptr with a custom deleter, but there is a problem here regarding the usage: I will not be able to pass points.data() to the function (as it will return RaiiPoint* and not Point* as accepted from Foo)

Comment: @JamesKanze: The RAII wrapper class could expose a `Get()` or `GetPtr()` method returning a `Point*` for interfacing with the legacy API.

Comment: @Mr.C64 His function requires a pointer to an array of `Point`.  Not an array of `RaiiPoint`.  Being able to convert a single `Point` doesn't help him much.

Comment: As @JamesKanze pointed out (preceding me in 32 seconds in the first comment :), I need a Point*.

Comment: @JohnnyW More importantly, you need a `Point*` which points to the first element of an array of `Point`, and not to a single `Point`.  Rather than defining a `RaiiPoint`, you probably need to define a `PointVector`, which maintains a `std::vector<Point>`, but ensures all of the necessary management of the individual `Point`.

Comment: Still wrapping the _raw_ `Point` resource in a **RAII** way makes sense. Then it's possible to store those safely wrapped resources in a `std::vector` (which _owns_ `RaiiPoint`s), and build a second _observing_ `std::vector<Point>`, that can be passed to the legacy API using `.data()` and `.size()` methods.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* use `std::vector<Point>`, calling `Foo( &v[0],
v.size() )`.  But managing the memory here could be tricky,
since `Point` apparently doesn't provide any clean copy and
assignment; a custom deleter in the allocator will be called for
each element, even if it is copied.

If the vector should actually own the points, then you can wrap
it in a more complex class, which calls `AllocPoint` for each
insertion (and inserts the results), and `DeallocPoint` for each
removal (and for everything remaining in the vector on
destruction).  This class should *not* allow write access to the
`Point` (non-const `operator[]`, non-const iterators, etc.),
however, since this would allow changing any pointers in
`Point`, and loosing what is needed for `DeallocPoint` to work
correctly.  Presumably, there other functions for manipulating
`Point`; you'll have to arrange for these to be available
through the wrapper interface.

Answer (score 1):

"You" could write a simple wrapper to free the memory:

```
struct PointVectorWrapper {
  vector<Point> points;
  ~PointVectorWrapper() {
    for (Point& p : points) {
      DeallocPoint(p);
    }
  }
  PointVectorWrapper& operator=(const PointVectorWrapper&) = delete;
  PointVectorWrapper(const PointVectorWrapper&) = delete;
};
// Now the usage is simple and safe:
PointVectorWrapper points;
// ... populate points ...
Foo(points.data(), points.size())
```

But this seems a little "adhoc". What's a more standard/reusable solution?

Comment: :-( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29  please edit your code to remove the danger

Comment: If it illustrates the point well enough, do we have to provide complete and safe solutions to everything for every question? Can't we rely on the OP to flesh it out into a full and safe implementation?

Comment: @BalogPal, indeed as Matthew Walton said I wanted to illustrate the point with a little clutter as possible. Nevertheless I edited the code.

Comment: I'm with Fred Brown here, only a fool leaves a loaded gun in hands of a child. Anyone has option to not post answer, those who do shall make it good quality. A wrapper intended as replacement for original must work the same, introducing undefined behavior after a copy is way wrong.

Comment: @BalogPal I agree with you but that is now fixed after the edit, isn’t it?

Comment: @JohnnyW: for the record, code necessary for correctness is NOT clutter

Comment: And how do you populate the `vector`?  That could be a critical point.

Comment: Copying a Point does a "shallow" copy of the pointer that a Point holds, so you could just do points.push_back(AllocPoint())

Comment: @JohnnyW Possibly.  Or simply create a function `PointVectorWrapper::push_back()` (no argument), since there's only one value you can actually push back.  But realistically, there must be additional functions which may need to be called (and exposed).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a standard vector with a custom allocator, that invoke AllocPoint on construct method and DeallocPoint() on destruct method.

```
template<typename T>
class CustomAllocator : public std::allocator<T>
{
  //Rebind and constructors
};

template<>
class CustomAllocator<Point> : public std::allocator<Point>
{
   //Rebind and constructors

   //For c++11
   void construct( pointer p )
   {
      new (p) Point();
      *p = AllocPoint();
   }

   void construct( pointer p, const_reference val )
   {
      construct(p);
      //copy member from val to point if neccessary 
   };   


   void destroy( pointer p )
   {
      DeallocPoint(*p);
      p->~Point();
   }
};

typedef std::vector<Point, CustomAllocator<Point> > PointVector;
```